# How Can I Specify the View to Load After Form Completion in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, self

Currently I have the following code which send the user back to the last active view:

`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

After researching `presentingViewController` I see that is what is causing this view to load.  Rather than sending the user to the last active view, I would like to specify the view where they will be redirected.  There must be a simple way to adjust this, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make much more sense to use a navigation stack for your needs. Instead of presenting this "form" with `presentViewController:`, embed your view controller within a navigation controller and use:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theForm animated:YES];
```

Afterwards, push the next controller onto the stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Can you provide a reference example of something similar for me to review?  I believe this would help me better understand the process.

Comment: I would start by reading some tutorials about Storyboards - this can all be done without a single line of code.